# Problem: While loop won't re-run the program properly

Tags: python, while-loop

```
user_input = input('Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:')

i = {'e': 1, 't': 1.5, 'a': 2, 'i': 2, 'n': 2, 's': 2, 'h': 2.5, 'r': 2.5, 'd': 2.5, 'l': 3, 'u': 3, 'c': 3.5, 'm': 3.5, 'f': 4, 'w': 4.5, 'y': 4.5, 'p': 5, 'g': 5, 'b': 5.5, 'v': 5.5, 'k': 5.5, 'q': 5.5, 'j': 6, 'x': 6, 'z':6}

totalValue = 0
    for char in user_input: # For every character in our string.
        if char in i: # If this character has a defined weight value.
            totalValue += i[char] # Add it to our total.

print('Word:', user_input, 'Score:', totalValue)


while user_input != 'nothing':
    user_input = input('Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:')

    if user_input != 'nothing':
    
        print('Word:', user_input, 'Score:', totalValue)
```

Result:

```
Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word: fazli
Word: fazli Score: 17
Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word: mia
Word: mia Score: 17
Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:
```

Currently, my program will print a score depending on what the user enters. After the first input, 'fazli' the score was 17.

My while loop is supposed to keep running until the user enters nothing.

The problem is my while loop I believe. It won't make a new score, it only copies the first one.

How can I keep running my while loop without it copying the first entered word score?

Comment: What *in the while loop* is supposed to be changing the score?

Comment: Well as you can see in the comments of my code, my program adds a score depending on each letter of a word the user enters. My code will keep running, but once the user types a new word, it copies the previous score. As you can see above, mia was typed but it copied 17 from fazli. How can I get my program to basically re-run the question and print a new score? @ScottHunter

Comment: your structure is wrong. You are only computing the score one time and using this same score again.

Comment: How can I fix that? This is what is troubling me. @sittsering

Comment: The for loop that calculates the score is only run once, the while loop repeatedly takes the input but never recalculates it. Please try and put the for loop inside the while loop or write it separately as a function or method.

Comment: @FazliBerisha i have posted it as answer

Comment: I understand what I did wrong now. I needed to combine my loops. Thank you all! @sittsering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you don't update the score in the while loop. you have to recalculate it with each iteration. I changed it for you.

```
i = {'e': 1, 't': 1.5, 'a': 2, 'i': 2, 'n': 2, 's': 2, 'h': 2.5, 'r': 2.5, 'd': 2.5, 'l': 3, 'u': 3, 'c': 3.5, 'm': 3.5, 'f': 4, 'w': 4.5, 'y': 4.5, 'p': 5, 'g': 5, 'b': 5.5, 'v': 5.5, 'k': 5.5, 'q': 5.5, 'j': 6, 'x': 6, 'z':6}
user_input = input('Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:')
while user_input != 'nothing':
    totalValue = 0
    for char in user_input: # For every character in our string.
        if char in i: # If this character has a defined weight value.
            totalValue += i[char] # Add it to our total.
    print('Word:', user_input, 'Score:', totalValue)
    user_input = input('Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = {'e': 1, 't': 1.5, 'a': 2, 'i': 2, 'n': 2, 's': 2, 'h': 2.5, 'r': 2.5, 'd': 2.5, 'l': 3, 'u': 3, 'c': 3.5, 'm': 3.5, 'f': 4, 'w': 4.5, 'y': 4.5, 'p': 5, 'g': 5, 'b': 5.5, 'v': 5.5, 'k': 5.5, 'q': 5.5, 'j': 6, 'x': 6, 'z':6}
#take user input
user_input = input('Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:')
#check if its not 'nothing'
while user_input != 'nothing':
    totalValue = 0
    #compute the score
    for char in user_input: 
        if char in i: 
            totalValue += i[char] 
    print('Word:', user_input, 'Score:', totalValue)
    #get user input again for next iteration
    user_input = input('Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:')
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also build it as a function as below

```py
i = {'e': 1, 't': 1.5, 'a': 2, 'i': 2, 'n': 2, 's': 2, 'h': 2.5, 'r': 2.5, 'd': 2.5, 'l': 3, 'u': 3, 'c': 3.5,
     'm': 3.5, 'f': 4, 'w': 4.5, 'y': 4.5, 'p': 5, 'g': 5, 'b': 5.5, 'v': 5.5, 'k': 5.5, 'q': 5.5, 'j': 6, 'x': 6, 'z': 6}


def calculate_score(word: str):
    totalValue = 0
    for char in word:  # For every character in our string.
        if char in i:  # If this character has a defined weight value.
            totalValue += i[char]  # Add it to our total.
    return totalValue


user_input = ''
while user_input != 'nothing':
    user_input = input('Welcome to the Scribble Scorer; Enter Word:')

    if user_input != 'nothing':
        totalValue = calculate_score(user_input)
        print('Word:', user_input, 'Score:', totalValue)
```